# Pull part of string using regExp in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Small question regrading taking part of string.
my string is

> some text here value: 100 .1.3.6 bla bla.

I would like to save the first part of the sting till the .1.3.......

so at the end ill have only

> some text here value: 100

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="some text here value: 100 .1.3.6 bla bla.";$str=~m{^([^.]*)} and print $1'
```

This matches from the beginning of the string until a dot character appears.  The matched portion is captured and printed if there was a match.

Comment: @user1734552 If this solved your problem, please accept the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for (assuming there's only one `:` per line).

```
perl -pe 's/(.*: [^ ]+).*/$1/' file.txt
```

Result:

```
some text here value: 100
```